# How to pass dynamic parameter (ID) to axios api call?

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vue-router, store, dynamic-url

I have an api with the last part dynamic:
src/api/user.js

```
export function getProfileData() {
  return request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/profile_update/DYNAMIC USER ID HERE',
    method: 'get',
  })
}
```

I am calling this api in this action:
store/modules/user.js

```
setProfileData({ commit }) {
 return getProfileData(userId).then(response => {
 console.log('RESPONSE setProfileData action dispatch', response)
 commit('SET_PROFILE_DATA', response.results)
})
```

(In this module I also have state and mutations - working)
This action is dispatched here:
src/views/users-list

```
goToUserProfile(user) {
  const userId = user.id
  this.$store.dispatch('user/setCurrentUser').then(() => {
    const profileData = this.$store.dispatch('user/setProfileData(userId)').then(() => {
      const profileData = this.$store.getters.profileData
      this.profileData = profileData
      console.log('users-list sending profile data: ', profileData )
      this.$router.push({
        name: 'SeeUserProfile',
        params: {
        userId: userId
      } 
    })
  }).catch((err) => {
     console.log('ERROR IN fetchin' userDataProfile: ', err)
     this.loading = false
   })
 })
}
```

The argument user comes from

```
@click.prevent="goToUserProfile(data.item), selectUser(data.item)"
```

So data.item = single selected user

This code is not working.
I need the dynamic user id to be used in the api.
In the store I also have:

```
setCurrentUser({ commit }, userData) {
commit('SET_CURRENT_USER', userData)}
```

which is working fine -inside userData there is the property id.

I tried using **/${params.userId}**, but how do I pass this in the api?

How do I pass the userId to the axios call?
Hope I’ve been clear.
I’ve extracted very much the code, so if needed I will post all of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add the id parameter for the `getProfileData` function `getProfileData(usedId)` and include it in the url:
  `url: http://localhost:8000/profile_update/${ DYNAMIC USER ID HERE }` (remember to enclose the link with backticks)
- Add the id parameter for the `setProfileData` function: `setProfileData({ commit }, userId)`
- If the id will be a route params, extract it using `this.$route.params.userId`

Hope this helps.

Use the backtips for the entire url instead of double quotes, and it works.

Comment: I tried it this way, but when I set the userId as a parameter in the action it stays grey. How to update it accordingly? I tried ```setProfileData({ commit }, userId) {
    return getProfileData(userId).then(response => {
      console.log('RESPONSE setProfileData action dispatch', response)
      commit('SET_PROFILE_DATA', response.results)
    })
  },``` but the request is not taken dynamic (it's read like this: 'http://localhost:8000/profile_update/$%7Bparams.userId%7D')

Comment: Also, in the console: unknown action type: user/setProfileData(userId).

Comment: Did you wrap the url in backticks?
Also, if you've added the user module to the main store file, you can refer to it directly `setProfileData(userId)` instead of `user/setProfileData(userId)`
Tip: Within `setProfileData`, print `userId` to the console before the return statement to verify its value.

Comment: The backticks should wrap the entire url or only the dynamic part? In ```export function getProfileData(userId) {
  return request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/profile_update/`${params.userId}`',
    method: 'get',
  })
}```  the parameter userId stays grey. And still unknown action type, even if the action above (written in the same way - /user/ ) doesn't show error.

Comment: Apologies. My previous comment was incorrect. 
From your first comment in this answer, you already set `userId` as a param for the `setProfileData` function. Remember to set it for the `getProfileData` function when you're exporting it `export function getProfileData(userId)`. Once you've set it there, you should be able to refer to it in the url property using ``url: 'http://localhost:8000/profile_update/`${ userId }`'``

Comment: It gives unknown action if ```('user/setProfileData(userId)')```. I need to write it as a string and no (). So this sorted. The param userId is sent with the button click (goToUserProfile), but setProfileData get it as undefined (I console log it as you suggested). ```export function getProfileData(userId) {
  return request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/profile_update/`${ userId }`',
    method: 'get',
  })
}``` is still not giving dynamic id (console: 'http://localhost:8000/profile_update/%60$%7B%20userId%20%7D%60'). The userId inside () is still grey.

Comment: Wrap the entire url with backticks instead of quotes.

Comment: Ok, something changed. Now it's actually taking the userId dynamically, but as in setProfileData it is undefined, now the request is 'http://localhost:8000/profile_update/undefined'. So, why does it get it undefined? Thanks for you patience @zer0kompression !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199176/discussion-between-zer0kompression-and-fdr).